# Removing multiple items using CheckBox from ListView and using Options Menu Item

Tags: android

I need to remove selected by chechbox items from `ListView` using a button from Options Menu. After selecting items, I'm trying to click delete button on Options Menu and then my application crashes. When I'm using same code when button is at the same xml where the listview everything goes correctly, problem only happen when I'm trying to do same thing using Options Menu Item.

EDIT: I'm pasting my whole code
This is my code from main_activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<String> items;
private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
private ListView lvItems;
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
Button delete;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_main);

    lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(id.lvItems);
    lvItems.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, layout.item_to_do, id.task_title, items);
    lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    items.add("Pierwsza rzecz");
    items.add("Druga rzecz");
    delete = (Button) findViewById(id.action_delete_task);
    setupListViewListener();
}

public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case id.task_delete:
            if (checked)

                break;
    }
}

private void setupListViewListener() {
    lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            items.remove(position);
            itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case id.action_add_task:
            final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
            taskEditText.setAllCaps(true);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Add a new task");
            builder.setMessage("What do you want to do next?");
            builder.setView(taskEditText);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Task to add: " + task);
                    itemsAdapter.add(task);
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(id.lvItems), string.add,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;

        case id.action_delete_task:
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = lvItems.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    int itemCount = lvItems.getCount();

                    for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) {
                            itemsAdapter.remove(items.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    checkedItemPositions.clear();
                    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: show your crash log

Comment: @RutvikBhatt java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please post complete code with `setupListViewListener` method

Comment: Your `delete` button is null, make sure your using a correct id

Comment: @Mosius yes seems like the `action_delete_task` is the id for the menu item not for the button.

Comment: I've pasted all of my code, setupListViewListener(); is method which i was using before I attempted to delete items using Options Menu Item

Answer (score 0):

delete is menu item not a view in your layout so you will not set click listener on it.

- Remove Button delete from your class
- And Just do like below

  ```
      case id.action_delete_task:
          SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = lvItems.getCheckedItemPositions();
          int itemCount = lvItems.getCount();
          for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
              if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) {
                  itemsAdapter.remove(items.get(i));
              }
          }
          checkedItemPositions.clear();
          itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  ```

Also I can not see onCreateOption menu in your code. This is used to inflate menu in your activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Sir, I've edited my initial post, so it includes whole code. After suggested changes, now my apllication doesn't crash, but it doesn't remove checked items.

Comment: You can ask if there is some crash, or some specific problem. Read out some tutorials. If you get some error then please ask.